# how to use Xcode 4.2.1 with ifort?

Tags: xcode, debugging, intel-fortran

I follow the guideline: (1) open a new project; (2) open a new empty file to built fortran code; (3) add build rule under build rule (choose Fortran source files for process using intel fortran XE).

However, the output window shows:
GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version gdb-1708) (Thu Nov  3 21:59:02 UTC 2011)
Copyright 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
GDB is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License, and you are
welcome to change it and/or distribute copies of it under certain conditions.
Type "show copying" to see the conditions.
There is absolutely no warranty for GDB.  Type "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-apple-darwin".tty /dev/ttys000
[Switching to process 19571 thread 0x0]
 Hello World!
Program ended with exit code: 0

Do I miss something here?